# Using FOIL in SML

Tags: list, sml, multiplication

I'm writing a small program that takes coefficients of two polynomials and FOILs them together, however I can only seem to multiply elements at the same indices.

```
fun polyMult([],[]) = []
  | polyMult(M, []) = []
  | polyMult([], N) = []
  | polyMult(M as x::xs, N as y::ys) = 
        (x * y) :: polyMult(M, ys);
```

I can successfully multiply the first element of `M` by every element of `N`, but then afterwards I want to be able to advance one element in `M` and then take that and multiply it by every element in `N`.

Is there any way I can advance the index in `M` and repeat the multiplication process? I.E

```
polyMult(tl(M) as x::xs, N as y::ys) = 
       (x * y) :: polyMult(M, ys);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines

```
fun foldL F y nil = y
    | foldL F y (x::xr) = foldL F (F(x,y)) xr;

fun polymult(M, nil) = nil
    | polymult(nil, N) = nil
    | polymult(m::mr, N) = foldL(fn(x,a) => x * a) m N::polymult(mr,N);
```

But you will need to figure out how to make it only accept real numbers and not integers as it does now ;)

Comment: What is `F` in this example?

Comment: F would be the function to apply, so if you look at 

foldL(fn(x,a) => x * a) m N::polymult(mr,N)

F would be (fn(x,a) => x * a)